# MuleSoft: DataWeave 2 Converting payload to DynamoDB Request

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

am trying to convert below sample json :

```
{
```

"SourceKeys": [
      {
         "key": "Branch",
         "value": "123"
      },
      {
         "key": "Code",
         "value": "456"
      }
   ]
}

to this format :

```
{
```

"M": {
      "Branch": {
         "S": "123"
      },
      "Code": {
         "S": "456"
      }
   }
}

Answer (score 1):

Start with the below  as a first step 
this:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

var data = {"SourceKeys": [ { "key": "Branch", "value": "123" }, { "key": "Code", "value": "456" } ] }

---
M: {(
    data."SourceKeys" map (item) -> { 
      (item.key) : {
        S: item.value
      }
    }
)}
```

gives a result as below

```
"M": {
  "Branch": {
    "S": "123"
  },
  "Code": {
    "S": "456"
  }
}
```

Hope this could help

Comment: I just edited answer to match the expected output, using the dynamic object feature  to change the `array of objects` into an `object`.